# ¿Qué puedo hacer para que mi código funcione de manera correcta y no se termine tan abruptamente?

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy intentando crear un switch para un juego, pero soy nuevo haciendo código, hasta ahora el código responde a ciertas partes, pero se termina de ejecutar abruptamente y no consigo que realice algunas actividades antes de que se finalice.
El código que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void Menu() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String op1 = null;
        String op2 = null;
        System.out.println("Welcome to cat & mouse game.");
        System.out.println("Would you like to play? y/n.");

    if(op1 !="y" || op1!="n") {
    do {

        op1 =keyboard.nextLine();

        //for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            switch(op1) {
            case "y":
                System.out.println("Introduce the coordinates to find the mouse");
                System.out.println("The format is n,n");
                System.out.println("Press 'y' to continue");
                op2=keyboard.nextLine();
                while(op2.equals("y")) {
                    System.out.println("Let's get start");
                    System.out.println("Write your coordinates");
                    System.out.println("Format (n,n)");

                    op2=keyboard.nextLine();
                    if(op2.equals("1,1")) {
                        System.out.println("Let's take a look");
                    }else 
                        if(op2=="1,2"){

                        }else
                            if(op2=="1,3"){

                            }else
                                if(op2=="1,4") {

                                }else
                                    if(op2=="1,5") {

                                    }else
                                        if(op2.equals("2,1")) {
                                            System.out.println("Vamo a ve");
                                        }else
                                            if(op2=="2,2") {

                                            }else
                                                if(op2=="2,3") {

                                                }else
                                                    if(op2=="2,4") {

                                                    }else
                                                        if(op2=="2,5") {

                                                        }else
                                                            if(op2=="3,1") {

                                                            }else
                                                                if(op2=="3,2") {

                                                                }else
                                                                    if(op2=="3,3") {

                                                                    }else
                                                                        if(op2=="3,4") {

                                                                        }else
                                                                            if(op2=="3,5") {

                                                                            }else
                                                                                if(op2=="4,1") {

                                                                                }else
                                                                                    if(op2=="4,2") {

                                                                                    }else
                                                                                        if(op2=="4,3") {

                                                                                        }else
                                                                                            if(op2=="4,4") {

                                                                                            }else
                                                                                                if(op2=="4,5") {

                                                                                                }else
                                                                                                    if(op2=="5,1") {

                                                                                                    }else
                                                                                                        if(op2=="5,2") {

                                                                                                        }else
                                                                                                            if(op2=="5,3") {

                                                                                                            }else
                                                                                                                if(op2=="5,4") {

                                                                                                                }else
                                                                                                                    if(op2=="5,5") {

                                                                                                                    }
                }
                break;
            case "n":
                //op1=keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Thank you");
                break;

                default: 
                System.out.println("Invalid character");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? y/n");


        //}
    }while(keyboard.equals("q"));
    System.out.println("The game has finished");
    keyboard.close();
    }

    //System.out.println("Invalid character");

    //return;

}
```

}

Comment: explica que termina abrutamente, en que parte?

Comment: @element no se si estoy bien o mal, pero si quiero que haga un ciclo para que se repita al final, no me permite, o si desde el principio ingreso un valor incorrecto, se finaliza y no me permite volver a intentarlo, a menos que lo vuelva a ejecutar

Comment: Entonces es un problema de tu lógica de control, podrías explicarnos tu lógica para ver donde tuviste la falla?

Comment: @RuslanLópez cuando finaliza el introducir las coordenadas aparece el mensaje de que si desea jugar otra vez, pero seguido de ello, el mensaje cuando se pasa el while y se termina la ejecución del programa

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta en el ultimo while. Va a valer false siempre pues comparas el objeto Scanner con un String.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
.......
}while(keyboard.equals("q"));
```

Sustituyelo por

```
}while(!keyboard.nextLine().equals("q"));
```

Comment: Aplique ese cambio, ahora me pregunta si quiero seguir jugando y al escribir cualquier tecla, se termina, ¿consideras que un ciclo for podría ayudarme a ciclar el juego antes de que finalice?

Comment: No, lo que tienes que hacer es negar el while. Te lo edito.